# Lock (disable editing) XML Cells when Opened with Excel

Tags: xml, excel

I need to create XML files which will be opened by different users, using Excel.

Is there a way of making some of the cells locked, so that the users cannot change their content? This would apply only to certain cells/columns.

If I understand correctly, since XML is a text file, there is no way of securely locking the document, but I can accept that,

Locking the cells to prevent accidental modification would help a lot, and the fact that someone can intentionally edit the XML (in Notepad) and unlock the cells is not ideal, but acceptable in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark the sheet as protected when using an XML file but not with a password, that is the limitation on XML as anyone would be able to open in notepad and read it if you could.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:x2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2003/xml" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:c="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:component:spreadsheet">
<OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"/>
<ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"/>
<Styles>
    <Style ss:ID="sUnlocked">
        <Protection ss:Protected="0"/>
    </Style>
</Styles>
<Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1" ss:Protected="1">
    <Table>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">sku</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">name</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">is_in_stock</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">qty</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">price</Data>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">A1234</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="String">Something</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="sUnlocked">
                <Data ss:Type="Number">17</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="sUnlocked">
                <Data ss:Type="Number">47</Data>
            </Cell>
            </Row>
    </Table>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Note you can unprotected any cells or rows by setting an unprotected style

```
<Style ss:ID="sUnlocked">
    <Protection ss:Protected="0"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: This is not working for me...I applied this style to one of my cell..but I can change values and settings of the cell... :(